# Google cloud VM Instance DNS error

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am having a bit of an issue with the VM Instances on google cloud.  I installed and set up apache and a website with it but now I am trying to configure a custom domain and when I try to add it in SSH I get the following error:

ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zone.create) ResponseError: status=403, code=Forbidden, reason(s)=insufficientPermissions
message=Insufficient Permission

I have also tried the directions at the following https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain and am getting a 404 not found error on my domain.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are having an issue with a VM instance and are trying to set up a custom domain. Those two are in very different realms. VM instances are under Compute Engine (except for Managed VMs, which live under App Engine, but that is beside the point). Custom Domains are features just of App Engine.

What do you mean that you are trying to "add it in SSH"? Did you mean DNS? If so, see my answer below.

What command are you running to get `ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zone.create) ResponseError: status=403, code=Forbidden, reason(s)=insufficientPermissions message=Insufficient Permission`?

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) apply to App Engine, not Compute Engine. That you are getting a 404 error is no surprise if you don't also have a corresponding app running in App Engine.

If you are trying to create a DNS hostname for a web site hosted on a VM instance on Compute Engine, I recommend that you either (a) use a static IP address and a static A record pointing to it, or (b) use an ephemeral IP address and set up a dynamic DNS A records pointing to it. (I use `freedns.afraid.org` for my DDNS.)